# How to do a preprocessing on tiles of a TileLayer before displaying them on Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet

I have a large image that I broke up in 256x256 tiles using gdal2tiles.py.

I display it on leaflet as a L.tileLayer. It works fine.

Now, I'd like to preprocess the 256x256 tiles before they are rendered in tileLayer.
I need to apply an algorithm on these stored tiles, and the algorithm generates tiles of same size, but with different content. It can looks like changing stored tiles content dynamically.

Is it possible to replace tiles that are in TileLayer with processed tiles ?

How should I proceed ?

I would like to process these tiles only once, so I guess I should take advantage of caching.

Comment: see https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#tileimage-display

Answer (score 1):

@IvanSanchez thank you for your answer.

I created a new tileLayer allowing to call a rest API doing predictions on tiles (taking and returning a base64-encoded PNG image).

```
/*
 * L.TileLayer.Infer, inspired by L.TileLayer.PixelFilter (https://github.com/GreenInfo-Network/L.TileLayer.PixelFilter/)
 */
L.tileLayerInfer = function (url, options) {
    return new L.TileLayer.Infer(url, options);
}

L.TileLayer.Infer = L.TileLayer.extend({
    // the constructor saves settings and throws a fit if settings are bad, as typical
    // then adds the all-important 'tileload' event handler which basically "detects" an unmodified tile and performs the pxiel-swap
    initialize: function (url, options) {
        L.TileLayer.prototype.initialize.call(this, url, options);
        // and add our tile-load event hook which triggers us to do the infer
        this.on('tileload', function (event) {
            this.inferTile(event.tile);
        });
    },

    // extend the _createTile function to add the .crossOrigin attribute, since loading tiles from a separate service is a pretty common need
    // and the Canvas is paranoid about cross-domain image data. see issue #5
    // this is really only for Leaflet 0.7; as of 1.0 L.TileLayer has a crossOrigin setting which we define as a layer option
    _createTile: function () {
        var tile = L.TileLayer.prototype._createTile.call(this);
        tile.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
        return tile;
    },

    // the heavy lifting to do the pixel-swapping
    // called upon 'tileload' and passed the IMG element
    // tip: when the tile is saved back to the IMG element that counts as a tileload event too! thus an infinite loop, as wel as comparing the pixelCodes against already-replaced pixels!
    //      so, we tag the already-swapped tiles so we know when to quit
    // if the layer is redrawn, it's a new IMG element and that means it would not yet be tagged
    inferTile: function (imgelement) {
        // already processed, see note above
        if (imgelement.getAttribute('data-InferDone')) return;

        // copy the image data onto a canvas for manipulation
        var width  = imgelement.width;
        var height = imgelement.height;
        var canvas    = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width  = width;
        canvas.height = height;
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        context.drawImage(imgelement, 0, 0);

        // encode image to base64
        var uri = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        var b64 = uri.replace(/^data:image.+;base64,/, '');

        var options = this.options;

        // call to Rest API
        fetch('/api/predict', {
            method: 'POST',
            mode: 'no-cors',
            credentials: 'include',
            cache: 'no-cache',
            headers: {
              'Content-type': 'application/json',
              'Accept': 'application/json',
              'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
              'image': [b64]
            })

          })
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((responseJson) => {
            // Perform success response.
            const obj = JSON.parse(responseJson);
            image = "data:image/png;base64," + obj["predictions"][0];
            var img = new Image();
            img.onload = function() {
              // draw retrieve image on tile (replace tile content)
              context.globalAlpha = options.opacity
              context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            }
            img.src = image;
            imgelement.setAttribute('data-InferDone', true);
            imgelement.src = image;

          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
          });
    }
});
```