# Liaflet tile layer as javascript object using base64

Tags: javascript, leaflet, base64

I found a great script for Leaflet here:
[How to do a preprocessing on tiles of a TileLayer before displaying them on Leaflet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62363197/how-to-do-a-preprocessing-on-tiles-of-a-tilelayer-before-displaying-them-on-leaf)

It gets data from a file, but I have a problem. My tiles are stored on a local device, and the browser blocks access to them. One of solutions is place the tiles in the body of the script as an object:

const Mytiles = [{tile_z : 15, tile_x : 22576, tile_y : 12896, tile_data : "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANS"},
{tile_z : 15, tile_x : 22576, tile_y : 12897, tile_data : "j7OwP7GSuFcLe0D7GuMrDXX1ix"}, ......];

where the tile_z, tile_x, tile_y are names of folders in the usual kind of bitmap tile storage (. / z / x / y.png) and the tile_data is base64 encoded png image.

How to change this script to work with such encoded tiles?

```
        /*
        L.TileLayer.Infer, inspired by L.TileLayer.PixelFilter (https://github.com/GreenInfo-Network/L.TileLayer.PixelFilter/)
         */
        L.tileLayerInfer = function (url, options) {
            return new L.TileLayer.Infer(url, options);
        }

        L.TileLayer.Infer = L.TileLayer.extend({
            // the constructor saves settings and throws a fit if settings are bad, as typical
            // then adds the all-important 'tileload' event handler which basically "detects" an unmodified tile and performs the pxiel-swap
            initialize: function (url, options) {
                L.TileLayer.prototype.initialize.call(this, url, options);
                // and add our tile-load event hook which triggers us to do the infer
                this.on('tileload', function (event) {
                    this.inferTile(event.tile);
                });
            },

            // extend the _createTile function to add the .crossOrigin attribute, since loading tiles from a separate service is a pretty common need
            // and the Canvas is paranoid about cross-domain image data. see issue #5
            // this is really only for Leaflet 0.7; as of 1.0 L.TileLayer has a crossOrigin setting which we define as a layer option
            _createTile: function () {
                var tile = L.TileLayer.prototype._createTile.call(this);
                tile.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
                return tile;
            },

            // the heavy lifting to do the pixel-swapping
            // called upon 'tileload' and passed the IMG element
            // tip: when the tile is saved back to the IMG element that counts as a tileload event too! thus an infinite loop, as wel as comparing the pixelCodes against already-replaced pixels!
            //      so, we tag the already-swapped tiles so we know when to quit
            // if the layer is redrawn, it's a new IMG element and that means it would not yet be tagged
            inferTile: function (imgelement) {
                // already processed, see note above
                if (imgelement.getAttribute('data-InferDone')) return;

                // copy the image data onto a canvas for manipulation
                var width  = imgelement.width;
                var height = imgelement.height;
                var canvas    = document.createElement("canvas");
                canvas.width  = width;
                canvas.height = height;
                var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
                context.drawImage(imgelement, 0, 0);

                // encode image to base64
                var uri = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
                var b64 = uri.replace(/^data:image.+;base64,/, '');

                var options = this.options;

                // call to Rest API
                fetch('/api/predict', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    mode: 'no-cors',
                    credentials: 'include',
                    cache: 'no-cache',
                    headers: {
                      'Content-type': 'application/json',
                      'Accept': 'application/json',
                      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                      'image': [b64]
                    })

                  })
                  .then((response) => response.json())
                  .then((responseJson) => {
                    // Perform success response.
                    const obj = JSON.parse(responseJson);
                    image = "data:image/png;base64," + obj["predictions"][0];
                    var img = new Image();
                    img.onload = function() {
                      // draw retrieve image on tile (replace tile content)
                      context.globalAlpha = options.opacity
                      context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                    }
                    img.src = image;
                    imgelement.setAttribute('data-InferDone', true);
                    imgelement.src = image;

                  })
                  .catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error)
                  });
            }
        });
```